# XML parsing in PHP with nested loop

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I have the following XML:

```
      <CruiseCharts Copyright="(C) Alsek Technologies, Inc." Exported="2014-01-10T18:34:01" ImagesUrlRoot="http://081198621a967d166a1f-e081145dd5e1f0f3f186009058a70a37.r71.cf1.rackcdn.com/">
      <Itinerary TotalFullDays="5" CruisingFullDays="5" StartLocationName="Tampa, Florida" EndLocationName="Tampa, Florida" DistributorName="Carnival" DistributorID="1" SmallMapFilename="166d7d841ae1de8315960a3f3d1e4dce.jpg" LargeMapFilename="564003962db32f0b21d8151ff99c0285.jpg" LargeMapHtmlMap="&lt;map name=&quot;map1&quot;&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;197,18,201,22&quot; title=&quot;Tampa, Florida&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;167,13,195,20&quot; title=&quot;Tampa, Florida&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;94,189,98,193&quot; title=&quot;Cozumel, Mexico&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;57,184,93,191&quot; title=&quot;Cozumel, Mexico&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;222,217,226,221&quot; title=&quot;George Town, Grand Cayman, Cayman Islands, United Kingdom&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;228,211,282,219&quot; title=&quot;George Town, Grand Cayman, Cayman Islands, United Kingdom&quot;/&gt;&lt;/map&gt;" DistributorLogoFilename="c1b9b02a38e72f5abf793979f5549c77.gif">
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="0" LocationName="Tampa, Florida, United States" DepartureTime="16:00:00" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="1" LocationName="At Sea" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="2" LocationName="Cozumel, Mexico" ArrivalTime="07:00:00" DepartureTime="15:00:00" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="3" LocationName="George Town, Grand Cayman, Cayman Islands, United Kingdom" ArrivalTime="10:00:00" DepartureTime="18:00:00" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="4" LocationName="At Sea" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="5" LocationName="Tampa, Florida, United States" ArrivalTime="08:00:00" />
        <Departure DepartureDate="2014-01-25" ShipName="Carnival Paradise" OperatorName="Carnival" DepartureID="37835048" ShipID="51" OperatorID="1" OperatorDepartureCode="20140125PA05" />
        <Departure DepartureDate="2014-11-15" ShipName="Carnival Paradise" OperatorName="Carnival" DepartureID="37835049" ShipID="51" OperatorID="1" OperatorDepartureCode="20141115PA05" />
        <Departure DepartureDate="2014-11-29" ShipName="Carnival Paradise" OperatorName="Carnival" DepartureID="37835050" ShipID="51" OperatorID="1" OperatorDepartureCode="20141129PA05" />
        <Departure DepartureDate="2014-12-13" ShipName="Carnival Paradise" OperatorName="Carnival" DepartureID="37835051" ShipID="51" OperatorID="1" OperatorDepartureCode="20141213PA05" />
        <Departure DepartureDate="2015-01-10" ShipName="Carnival Paradise" OperatorName="Carnival" DepartureID="37835052" ShipID="51" OperatorID="1" OperatorDepartureCode="20150110PA05" />
        <Departure DepartureDate="2015-02-07" ShipName="Carnival Paradise" OperatorName="Carnival" DepartureID="37835053" ShipID="51" OperatorID="1" OperatorDepartureCode="20150207PA05" />
      </Itinerary>
      <Itinerary TotalFullDays="7" CruisingFullDays="7" StartLocationName="Miami, Florida" EndLocationName="Miami, Florida" DistributorName="Carnival" DistributorID="1" SmallMapFilename="9eb6e4f1f6ba2e6e174e97492f5a7e8e.jpg" LargeMapFilename="8a508e8f9049ff5088e875de2c598364.jpg" LargeMapHtmlMap="&lt;map name=&quot;map1&quot;&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;234,18,238,22&quot; title=&quot;Miami, Florida&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;209,13,233,20&quot; title=&quot;Miami, Florida&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;93,129,97,133&quot; title=&quot;Cozumel, Mexico&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;55,123,91,130&quot; title=&quot;Cozumel, Mexico&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;209,154,213,158&quot; title=&quot;George Town, Grand Cayman, Cayman Islands, United Kingdom&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;215,148,269,156&quot; title=&quot;George Town, Grand Cayman, Cayman Islands, United Kingdom&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;77,166,81,170&quot; title=&quot;Costa Maya, Mexico&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;82,160,174,168&quot; title=&quot;Costa Maya, Mexico&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;102,216,106,220&quot; title=&quot;Mahogany Bay, Roat&amp;#225;n Island, Honduras&quot;/&gt;&lt;area href=&quot;#&quot; onClick=&quot;return false&quot; shape=&quot;rect&quot; coords=&quot;75,222,133,230&quot; title=&quot;Mahogany Bay, Roat&amp;#225;n Island, Honduras&quot;/&gt;&lt;/map&gt;" DistributorLogoFilename="c1b9b02a38e72f5abf793979f5549c77.gif">
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="0" LocationName="Miami, Florida, United States" DepartureTime="16:00:00" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="1" LocationName="At Sea" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="2" LocationName="Cozumel, Mexico" ArrivalTime="08:00:00" DepartureTime="17:00:00" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="3" LocationName="Costa Maya, Mexico" ArrivalTime="08:00:00" DepartureTime="16:00:00" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="4" LocationName="Mahogany Bay, Roatan Island, Honduras" ArrivalTime="08:00:00" DepartureTime="15:00:00" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="5" LocationName="George Town, Grand Cayman, Cayman Islands, United Kingdom" ArrivalTime="10:00:00" DepartureTime="18:00:00" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="6" LocationName="At Sea" />
        <ItineraryItem CalendarDayOffset="7" LocationName="Miami, Florida, United States" ArrivalTime="08:00:00" />
        <Departure DepartureDate="2015-01-04" ShipName="Carnival Splendor" OperatorName="Carnival" DepartureID="37827160" ShipID="40026" OperatorID="1" OperatorDepartureCode="20150104SL07" />
        <Departure DepartureDate="2015-02-08" ShipName="Carnival Splendor" OperatorName="Carnival" DepartureID="37835054" ShipID="40026" OperatorID="1" OperatorDepartureCode="20150208SL07" />
      </Itinerary>
  </CruiseCharts>
```

I am parsing it but i am getting as below result

```
 # text =
 Itinerary =
 # text = 
 empty values in tag
```

I have to parse this xml in PHP. how can i parse it and get values in each iteration as below format

`TotalFullDays="5" CruisingFullDays="5" StartLocationName="Tampa, Florida"` ... of each XML tag.

Itinerary, ItineraryItem, Departure tag.

I want to show the data in this format

> http://asu.cruisecharts.com/departure.aspx?0=37827127

**EDIT:** This is my current code:

```
<?php
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load("alsek_cruisecharts.xml");
    $x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
    foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item) {
        print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please provide your PHP code that attempts to do what you want to do.

Comment: <?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("alsek_cruisecharts.xml");

$x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item)
  {
  print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br>";
  }
?> this code i am using but it returns empty value

Comment: Also i am using this code but it returns values of Itinerary not for the Departure and ItineraryItem the code is as below           <?php $xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->Itinerary[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
?> where $string is xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to *render* it but here's one way to parse it. Turns it into an array of objects.

```
try {
    $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load('file.xml');

    if($xmlDoc===false)
        { throw new Exception('File not found.'); }

    $root = $xmlDoc->documentElement;

    $charts = array();

    foreach($root->getElementsByTagName('Itinerary') as $itinerary) {
        $chart = array();
    #   get attributes
        foreach($itinerary->attributes as $attribute)
            { $chart[$attribute->name] = $attribute->value; }

    #   get items
        $chart['Itinerary'] = array();

        foreach($itinerary->getElementsByTagName('ItineraryItem') as $itineraryItem) {
            $item = array();

            foreach($itineraryItem->attributes as $attr)
                { $item[$attr->name] = $attr->value; }

            $chart['Itinerary'][] = $item;
        }

    #   get departures
        $chart['Departures'] = array();

        foreach($itinerary->getElementsByTagName('Departure') as $departure) {
            $item = array();

            foreach($departure->attributes as $attr)
                { $item[$attr->name] = $attr->value; }

            $chart['Departures'][] = $item;
        }

        $charts[] = $chart;
    }

#   objectify
    $charts = json_decode(json_encode($charts));

#   print structure
#   print_r($charts);

    foreach($charts as $chart) {
    #   use it
    }
}
catch (Exception $exc) {
    die($exc->getMessage());
}
```

You can use it like so:

Get the `DistributorName` of the first `Itinerary`:

```
$charts[0]->DistributorName;
```

Get the `LocationName` of the second `ItineraryItem` in the first `Itinerary`:

```
$charts[0]->Itinerary[1]->LocationName;
```

Get the `ShipId` of the third `Departure` in the second `Itinerary`:

```
$charts[1]->Departures[2]->ShipId;
```

If you want to do some formatting like converting `CruiseCharts/Itinerary/Departure/DepartureDate` into a proper `DateTime` object you'll want to look at the `foreach` loops where I'm accessing the `attributes` properties.

Comment: Thanks Dissident i think this will help me, I will try to make this code on my page lets see.. thanks for this..